# How do I find a range of numbers in the content of file and move files containing the range of numbers to another directory?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files

Okay so I have about 90 files, each with a body like

```
187942           78.9
```

I want to filter files that has the values between 70 to 90 on the second column and move them to another directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small script with `awk` to distinguish good/bad files. E.g., something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p another-directory
for f in * ; do 
    if ! awk '$2>=70 && $2<=90 { exit 1; }' "$f" ; then
        mv -- "$f" another-directory/
    fi
done
```

The key here is that `exit 1` is a fail exit, so the condition phrase with `awk` just discovers the presence of a line where the second token is a number between 70 and 90 (inclusive). Otherwise, `awk` exits normally, with success. The exclamation mark negates it, making the condition be true when the file has a good line, and false otherwise.

Comment: Why not exit with 0 and remove the negation?

Comment: Yes, maybe; I had difficulty to make awk end in failure at end of input whilst ending successfully when forced (it seemed the END phrase took effect either way, making things more complicated). But maybe I didn't test it too well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$2>70&&$2<90&&!a[FILENAME]++{printf("%s%c",FILENAME,0)}' * | xargs -0 cp -vt target/ --
```

Explanation:

- `$2>70&&$2<90` the condition.
- `!a[FILENAME]++` will be true if the filename is unique (the filename will be printed only once).
- `printf("%s%c",FILENAME,0)` prints the filename with null byte delimiter, to cope with special filenames.
- `xargs -0` reads the filenames null byte delimited.
- `cp -vt target/ --` copies the files to directory `target/`.

Comment: 1. How could `*` yield several identical filenames? 2. The OP requested move, not copy :-) 3. Spaces would make your awk command easier to read, especially for a beginner.

Comment: @L.Levrel 1. `*` does not yield several identical filenames, but awk checks lines. If there are multiple lines, awk would print it multiple times. 2. remove `cp` with `mv`, the command stays the same.

Comment: good one; couldn't you rather use `nextfile` upon hits so as to avoid the multiple file problem?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Yes, you could, but `nextfile` is `gawk` only, I tried to provide a portable solution.

Comment: I might need further explanations on how this works. How does !a[FILENAME]++ work? and printf("%s%c",FILENAME,0) as well. By filename, am I inputting the entire pathway? The directory to my files are like this. /home/hp-litedesk/Desktop/2000/2000challenge/blast/ and I am moving them to /home/hp-litedesk/Desktop/2000/2000challenge/7090/